# other ports maps to other ip with same domain name

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx

I'm trying to use node.js with https.
the problem is our ssl certificate is verified to our main domain so our node.js app is without ssl certificate and browser refuse to load it.

the solution that we have in mind is:

Our main server is nginx.

at the moment https://example.com points to the usuall server.

is there anyway to point  example.com:2020 to another ip so node.js app can be loaded with the same domainname?

or anything we do with nginx?

OR any other way to achieve this?

We use node.js app to create a live static.

P.S: Main domain is behind cloudflare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location /download {
            rewrite     /download/(\d+) /sc?i=$1 break;
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5008;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3500;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please explain where should i add node.js server ip and port?